# Validation of Parameters based on value of type attribute of test element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two xml files given below.

```
<!-- First XML -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test type="survey">
<parameter name="surveyname">Survey</parameter>  
</test>

<!-- Second XML -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test type="test">
<parameter name="mode">Normal</parameter>  
<parameter name="rdttype"></parameter>
</test>
```

Below are my questions on validation of above xml files using xml schema.

1. Is it possible to validate these two xml files using single XML schema ?
2. When the value of type attribute from test element is "survey", in xml i need to have a single parameter as given in first xml.
3. When the value of type attribute from test element is "test", in xml i need to have two parameters as given in second xml.
4. Also i want to validate the values of parameters using the same schema.

Can any body help me in writing the schema for validating these xml files.

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of rules you need XSD 1.1 or some extension for XSD 1.0 such as Schematron.

The XSD 1.1 schema below validates the example XML you provided considering the rules you listed using XSD 1.1 assertions. If you remove the `<xs:assert>` it will work in XSD 1.0, but then you will have to provide some other means to enforce the rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="name">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:enumeration value="mode" />
                                            <xs:enumeration value="surveyname" />
                                            <xs:enumeration value="rdttype" />
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:attribute>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="test" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="survey" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:assert test="(@type = 'survey'
                                and count(parameter) = 1 
                                and parameter/@name = 'surveyname' 
                                and parameter = 'Survey') 
                             or (@type = 'test' 
                                and count(parameter) = 2 
                                and parameter[1]/@name = 'mode' 
                                and parameter[1] = 'Normal' 
                                and parameter[2]/@name = 'rdttype' 
                                and parameter[2] = '')"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```